# How should I test a complex method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a complex method I want to test,
It recieves user, UserUpdatedDetails(password, restore question and email) and password.

#### And it should check the following:

1. Make sure user updated all fields that he had to
2. Validate each field independently
3. Make sure password matches user password(Authenticate)
4. Update the required fields
5. If password / Question Answer has changed, re-encrypt special key for sensitive data (it's a random long key that is used to encrypt sensitive data such as birthday, first name and stuff... the key is also saved by the encryption of password and question answer not the point right now).

The main method uses small methods, that uses other small methods.
The thing is they are all private methods, and there is no reason they should be otherwise (I am not going to use them anywhere else)

Testing this all thing is going to be a nightmare, And even if I would test each small method independently, It doesn't give me a clear picture that the main method is doing what it has to be doing.

#### the Implementation looks somthing like this:

```
UpdateUserDetails(this User user,
                  UserDetails userDetails,
                  string Password,
                  out ErrorList<AuthErrors> errorList)
{
    UpdateActions actions;
    errorList = user.ValidateUserDetails(userDetails, out actions);
    if (errorList.IsSuccess() && actions != UpdateActions.None)
    {
         var status = Auth(user.UserId, password); // Easy to mock
         if (status.IsSuccess)
         {
             try
             {
                 var newUser = user.UpdateUserDetails(userDetails, actions);
                 commit;
                 return newUser;
             }
             catch
             {
                 rollback;
                 throw;
             }
         }
         else
             errorList.Add(AuthErrors.WrongPassword);
    }
    return null;
}
enum UpdateActions
{
    None = 0,
    Password = 1,
    Email = 2,
    Question = 4,
    All = Password & Email & Question
}
```

Edit:
By the way, It easy for me to Mock the Auth implementation, and also the DAL implemention(Updaing the user) all the other is the problem...

***Just to give some point of view on the methods inside methods:***

```
ValidateUserDetails(this User user, 
                    UserDetails userDetails,
                    out UpdateActions actions)
{
    actions = UpdateActions.None;
    ErrorList<AuthErrors> errorList = new ErrorList<AuthErrors>()
    if (userDetails.password != null || user.RequirePasswordUpdate)
    {
        errorList.AddRange(validatePassword(userDetails.password) // PublicMethod, already, which has tests.
        actions.Add(UpdateActions.Password) // ExtensionMethod
    }
    if (userDetails.email != null || user.RequireEmailUpdate)
    {
        errorList.AddRange(validateEmail(userDetails.Email) // PublicMethod, already, which has tests.
        actions.Add(UpdateActions.Email) // ExtensionMethod
    }
    if (userDetails.Question != null || userDetails.QuestionAnswer || user.RequireQuestionUpdate)
    {
        errorList.AddRange(validateQuestion(userDetails.Question, userDetails.QuestionAnswer) // PublicMethod, already, which has tests.
        actions.Add(UpdateActions.Question) // ExtensionMethod
    }
}
UpdateUserDetails(this User user, UserDetails userDetails, UpdateActions actions, string oldPassword)
{
    if (actions.Has(UpdateActions.UpdatePassword)
        user.UpdatePassword(userDetails.password)
    ...
    return DataAccess.UpdateUser(user); // Easy to Mock
}
UpdatePassword(this User user, string password, string oldPassword)
{
    user.Password = _IEncryptionManager.BcryptEncrypt(password); // easy to mock encryption methods
    user.SensKey = _IEncryptionManager.DesEncrypt(_IEncryptionManager.DesDecrypt(user.SensKey,
                                                          oldPassword),
                           password);
                                      
}
```

I'd appreciate the help, 
Thanks regards, 
Amir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with testing private bits, `UpdateUserDetails` is what you're interested in and this method should be tested primarly. Private parts will get tested as kind of *collateral damage* of public method tests. Best part is, you already know what you should test and you specified it yourself with the list you posted. However, it could be improved a bit:

> Make sure user updated all fields that he had to

This essentially is input data checking and should be tested as such (what happens whenuser posted incomplete data? Exception, error message? This is what you want to test/verify - *what happens* when user didn't update all fields and *whether it happened indeed*).

> Validate each field independently

What happens when field is invalid? This is what should be tested (exception thrown, error message or so). Successful validation leads to successful update, and that will be tested in the final step.

> Make sure password matches user password(Authenticate)

Usually authentication is heavy/complex process. Does it really need to be private as a part of user details update? Unless you have a very good reason to keep it this way, I'd say it's a good candidate to extract to separate being and inject as dependency.

> Update the required fields

This is the tested unit here and whether those fields got updated properly should be tested at this point.

> If password / Question Answer has changed, re-encrypt special key for sensitive data (it's a random long key that is used to encrypt sensitive data such as birthday, first name and stuff... the key is also saved by the encryption of password and question answer not the point right now).

Key generation should be done elsewhere, as in, it sounds like different responsibility than updating user details and maybe it's worth to test it as such.

Comment: You right, I did moved by your advice the key generation to a different class which I can test independently. But now I have another question: Do I have to test functionality that I already tested somewhere else? (for example, I already have tests for ValidatePassword and ValidateEmail and ValidateQuestion... should I test for it also in my UpdateUserDetails method? Thanks.

Comment: @Amir: you shouldn't. For `UpdateUserDetails` your *validate* methods are implementation details and you don't want to bind those two too strictly. For `UpdateUserDetails` validation is relevant only as whole, as it either succeeds or not - those are your two scenarios related to validation when testing `UpdateUserDetails`. Most likely you'll extra test to verify what happens then, say *WhenValidationFails_UpdateUserDetails_DoesSomething*. Like I said, validation success is tested later, and is precondition for entire update success.

Answer (score 1):

You should unit test each feature indcvidually first, since your `UpdateUserDetails()` first validate user details using `ValidateUserDetails()`, then check the authentications for the user using the `Auth()`, etc..

Then, you should first create the following unit tests:

- `CanValidateUserDetails()`
- `WontAddUserWithWrongPassword()`
- `CanAddUserWithValidPassword()`
- `CanAuthenticateUser()`.
- ...

After *asserting* that all of these methods (features) *passed* there tests, then just unit test only what the `UpdateUserDetails()` actually does which is:

```
user.UpdateUserDetails(userDetails, actions);
```

Through:

- `CanUpdateUserDetails()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to travel through all the available paths in this method in order to achieve this try to use some available mocking frameworks like rhino mocks. Mock all the inputs of your method by using mocking framework in order to generate a different behavior internally.

Answer (score 0):

Your can make your Unit Test project "see" the private methods by using the `InternalsVisible` (MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx)) attribute in `AssemblyInfo.cs` of the project that contains the methods.

But, if you need to use it, this might indicate architectural problems in your solution.

Another option would be to use some function that returns an status code that indicates the success of your workflow (instead of using the extension method that you posted above). Then you could test for the different return values in your Unit Tests.